# Completeness of $L^p$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have some doubts with the proof on this theorem (Bartle Elements of Integration)

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ The vector space $L^p(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is complete with the norm

$$ \Vert \overline{f} \Vert_p = (\int \vert f \vert ^p )^{1/p} $$

I will write $f$ instead of your class.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $L^p$. Then, exists a subsequence $(g_k)$ of $(f_n)$ such that $\Vert g_{k+1}-g_k \Vert < 2^{-k}$. Define

$$ (*)g(x) = \vert g_1(x) \vert + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \vert g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x) \vert \implies \vert g(x) \vert ^p = (\vert g_1(x) \vert + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \vert g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x) \vert)^p$$

Note that $g: X \rightarrow \overline{R}$ is measurable and $g \geq 0$. Then by Fatou's lemma (notice that the sequence on the right converges to $\vert g \vert ^p$)

$$ \int \vert g \vert^p d\mu \leq \text{liminf}\int (\vert g_1(x) \vert + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \vert g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x) \vert)^p d\mu $$

$$ \implies (\int \vert g \vert^p d\mu)^{1/p} \leq \text{liminf} \lbrace \int (\vert g_1(x) \vert + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \vert g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x) \vert)^p d\mu \rbrace^{1/p} $$

By Minkowski's and because $\Vert g_{k+1}-g_k \Vert < 2^{-k}$ we have

$$ \implies (\int \vert g \vert^p d\mu)^{1/p} \leq \text{liminf} (\Vert g_1 \Vert_p + \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert g_{k+1} - g_k \Vert_p) = 1 + \Vert g_1 \Vert_p  $$

$\textbf{Here comes my first question}$, in the book it says that if we consider $E=\{x \in X / g(x)< \infty \}$  then $E \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mu(X \setminus E)=0$. I can't understand why $\mu(X \setminus E)=0$. After this he says that $g$ converges $\mu-a.e$ (I guess it will refer to (*)) and $g \chi_{E}$ is in $L^p$.

$\textbf{Here my second question}$, because it is necessary to work with E?. I know that $g$ can take $\infty$, but from the above we can see that $\int \vert g \vert^p d\mu < \infty $ because $g_1 \in L^p$ and so $\Vert g_1 \Vert_p < \infty$ and then $g \in L^p$.

Anyway, following the proof of the book, we define $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x) = g_1(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x), \hspace{0.1cm} x\in E $$

$$f(x) = 0, \hspace{0.1cm} x\notin E $$

Applying the triangle inequality we have $\vert g_k \vert \leq \vert g_1 \vert + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \vert g_{j+1}-g_j \vert \leq g$ and then $\vert g_k \vert^p \leq g^p$. Because $\vert g_k \vert^p \rightarrow \vert f \vert^p$ converge in $E$ (i.e $\mu$-a.e) by the Dominated Convergence Theorem : $f \in L^p$.

Then we have $\vert f -g_k \vert \leq 2 \text{max}\{ \vert f \vert, \vert g_k \vert \}\leq 2g $ i.e $\vert f-g_k \vert^p \leq 2^p g^p$, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem

$$ 0 = \int \lim \vert f-g_k \vert^p = \lim \int \vert f-g_k \vert^p \implies \lim \Vert f-g_p \Vert_p = 0 $$

Then $g_k \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$. Finally, because $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, for $\epsilon > 0$, exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n>n_0$ implies

$$ \int \vert f_m-f_n \vert^p < \Vert f_m - f_n \Vert_p <\epsilon^p $$

$\textbf{Here my third question}$, in the book says that we have consider $k$ (bigger) such that

$$ \int \vert f_m-g_k \vert^p < \epsilon^p $$

What means this ?, I understand that means that we can always choose a index of subsequence such that is greater than $n_0$ but I'm not sure.

And then applying Fatou's Lemma

$$ \int \vert f_m-f \vert^p \leq \text{liminf} \int \vert f_m-g_k \vert ^p  \leq \epsilon^p $$

And then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, so $L^p$ is complete.

Thank you very much for reading all this proof and I hope you can understand what my doubts were.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your second question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Where exactly is the typo?

Comment: I don’t understand this:
Here my second question
, because it is necessary to work with E?

Comment: Why does it prove that $g \chi_{E} \in L^p$. According to me $g\in L^p$ 
as I mentioned below.

Comment: Right after mention of Dominated Convergence Theorem in second question, there seems to be a typo where it says $g_{p}$, should be $g_{k}$.

Answer (score 2):

First question: if $\mu(X / E)>0$, then you will get an immediate contradiction of the upperbound above that question, since in this case the integral of $|g|^p$ must be infinite.

Second question: The point here is that the limit of this Cauchy sequence should be a function in $L^p$, i.e. it maps $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The work up to this point is basically a construction of the limit, but that construction only defines it up to sets of measure zero. This is not a concern though, since you can redefine the limit on this measure zero set, X\E, arbitrarily, in this case to be equal to zero, and this will still define the limit in $L^p$.

Third question: Remember $g_k$ is a subsequence of $f_m$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the answers to the first two questions. In the third, is it because the set of indices of $(g_k)$ is infinite?

Comment: No prob! To clarify a bit further, notice that since you have assumed $f_m$ is Cauchy in $L^p$, there exists $n_0$ so that $m,n \ge n_0$ implies $\|f_m - f_n\|_p < \epsilon$. Remember $g_k$ is a subsequence of $f_m$, i.e. for all $k$, $g_k = f_j$ for some $j$. Thus there must exist a point $n_1$ so $m,k \ge n_1$ implies  $\|f_m - g_k\|_p < \epsilon$. In other words, the $g_k's$ are really just $f_m's$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!